# SAS remove the last characters if special

Tags: sql, sas, substring, sas-macro

I have a sas dataset with the variable called response, which has the following records:

[image]

and so on.

These are all the same records, I need to remove the last character wherever special and return the records as

[image]

When I use a compress function, it removes the asterisk in between and returns:
TrailerOffer which is not what I want.
Can somebody please help me code this? I need to remove the last characters if these are special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression character classes to specify the 'special' trailing characters.  In this example replacement pattern, any characters that are not letters or numbers will be removed.  `\s*` is needed before `$` because SAS character variables will have trailing spaces when their values are passed to the regex engine.

Learn more about regular expression class groupings in the [SAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p0s9ilagexmjl8n1u7e1t1jfnzlk.htm#p12dxk6qpmhaddn11dk5jo73i9h4)

```
data have;
length response $20.; input response; datalines;
Trailer*Offer
Trailer*Offer*
Trailer*Offer???
Trailer*Offer?...
Offer#1
Offer#1?
Offer#1*?
;
data want;
  set have;
  response = prxchange ('s/[^a-z0-9]+\s*$//i', 1, response);
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [PRXCHANGE](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/edmcdc/v_017/ds2ref/p1jpfpfp9qw3ron1501s0x5lpjw9.htm)

```
prx=prxchange("s/^W*(.*?)\W*$/$1/",-1, response);
```

will remove trailing special characters

```
data have;
length response $20.;
response="Trailer*Offer";output;
response="Trailer*Offer*";output;
response="Trailer*Offer???";output;
response="Trailer*Offer?...";output;
run;

data _null_;
set have;
prx=prxchange("s/^W*(.*?)\W*$/$1/",-1, response);
put prx;
run;
```

```
 77         
 78         data _null_;
 79         set have;
 80         prx=prxchange("s/^W*(.*?)\W*$/$1/",-1, response);
 81         put prx;
 82         run;
 
 Trailer*Offer
 Trailer*Offer
 Trailer*Offer
 Trailer*Offer
```

Comment: Thanks Kermit, was not sure how to use prxchange, this is very helpful!